# Hard code value into data map for Dynamics CRM

Tags: import, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a file that I want to import into Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 using the native import utility. The file does not contain a field that is required on the entity I want to import onto, is it possible to set the value for the field in the data map?

EG. The required field is "Source" and I want it to always be set to "Tech Survey" without adding it to the source file. Can I add something to the data map that will fill out this field for me on import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create and add prevalidation plugin that sets the field for you automatically, but in my mind, that seems more difficult then just updating the file...